# Clojure list comprehension - run inner loop only once in certain circumstance?

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to use a single list comp to achieve the following or do I need some other method?

```clj
(def args '([[:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4]] {:a 1 :b 2}))


(defn myfunc []
  "Want to run inner loop only once if arg is a map."
  (for [arg args [cmd & params] arg] ; 'cmd & params' are meaningless if map.
    (if (map? arg)
      arg
      (into [cmd] params))))
```

Above code produces

```
=> [[:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4] {:a 1, :b 2} {:a 1, :b 2}]
```

But I actually want

```clj
=> [[:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4] {:a 1, :b 2}]
```

Obviously this isn't the full function, I'm doing transforms if the arg is in vector form but want to let map form pass straight through (without being duplicated).

**Update**: I've found that a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) has its roots in [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), whereas 'conditionally executing the inner loop' is actually an imperative notion, so it's not surprising this isn't easy to express with ***a single*** list comprehension, which is a totally fp construct.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this what you want to do?:**
Build a new sequence from an existing sequence. For every element in the input sequence, there are two possible cases:

- It is a map: In that case, just append it to the result sequence
- Otherwise it is a sequence and its elements should possibly be transformed and appended to the result sequence

If this is what you want to do, this computation can conveniently be expressed by first mapping the elements of the input sequence to subsequences and then concatenating those sequences to form the resulting sequence.

As suggested by @cfrick, there is `mapcat` that combines mapping with concatenation, either by passing in a sequence directly to `mapcat`

```
(mapcat (fn [x] (if (map? x) [x] x)) args)
```

or by using `mapcat` as a transducer

```
(into [] (mapcat (fn [x] (if (map? x) [x] x))) args)
```

I don't think `for` is suitable for expressing this computation.

Comment: `(mapcat (fn [x] (if (map? x) [x] x)))` as transducer seems to do the same (at least for the given test case)

Comment: @cfrick I had totally forgotten about `mapcat`. This is a great improvements, things become a lot more concise!

Answer (score 0):

before I propose a solution, I have a few remarks on the function `myfunc` that you provided:

- the doc string is misplaced. I know it's weird but the doc string must be before the arguments of a function, so before `[]`,
- your usage of `for` instruction is not what you expect I think. You should take a look on the example in [the documentation here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for). Mainly the `for` instruction is nice to construct Cartesian product from list.

I hope that I understood correctly what you want to achieve. In my proposition, I use a recursion through `loop` instruction to build a vector which will contain every arguments:

```clj
(defn myfunc "Want to run inner loop only once if arg is a map."
  [& args]
  (loop [arg-to-parse args
         res          []]
    (if (empty? arg-to-parse)
      res
      (let [arg              (first arg-to-parse)
            new-arg-to-parse (rest  arg-to-parse)]
        (if (map? arg)
          (recur new-arg-to-parse (conj res arg))
          (recur new-arg-to-parse (into res arg))
          )))))

(myfunc [[:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4]] {:a 1 :b 2})
;; => [[:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4] {:a 1, :b 2}]
(myfunc {:a 1 :b 2} [[:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4]])
;; => [{:a 1, :b 2} [:db/foo 1 2] [:db/bar 3 4]]
```